# Should I use faker or faster faker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

We are trying to start a new rails project and for our testing purposes, we intend to use faker. Is faster faker (ffaker) a superset of faker, which one should I be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ffaker README](http://rubydoc.info/github/EmmanuelOga/ffaker/master/file/README.rdoc#Ffaker___Faker) claims there is little difference, and that has been my experience thus far.

Comment: Since I am planning on a new app, just would like to know which gem should I use going forward.

Comment: The API's are the same, if you change gems then the code should be exactly the same, so it doesn't really matter. Then I'd choose ffaker since it's faster.

Comment: FFaker is missing some namespaces such as Business. This is essential if you want to simulate fake credit card data and such. I'm sure there are other namespaces that are not defined in FFaker. I personally think Faker is more complete.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2022, [faker seems a little better maintained](https://ruby.libhunt.com/compare-ffaker-vs-faker):

> ffaker activity: declining
>
> faker activity: growing

Bear in mind, that's based on the arbitrary opinion of one website.

A quick inspection of [ffaker](https://github.com/ffaker/ffaker) vs [faker](https://github.com/faker-ruby/faker) github repos show many more commits in faker, and more recent commits in faker (perhaps an indication of it being better maintained).

This is from 10 minutes scouting the web. Happy to be corrected on any of the above.